# Bypass spool when using thirdparty database spooling

Tags: database, symfony, swiftmailer, spool

I'm using a thirdparty bundle (`Dextervip Citrax\DatabaseSwiftmailerBundle`) to spool my email in a database. However, I still want to be able to bypass the spooling for some specific actions. Before, when I didn't use the bundle and used just regular spooling, I did this the following way:

```
public function sendSeparateMessage($subject, $fromEmail, $toEmail, $toCc, $body, $bypassSpool = false){

  $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject($subject)
  ->setFrom($fromEmail)
  ->setTo($toEmail)
  ->setCc($toCc)
  ->setBody($body)
  ->setContentType("text/html");


  // Send the message
  $failedRecipients = [];
  $numSent = 0;

  foreach ($toEmail as $address => $name)
  {
    if (is_int($address)) {
      $toEmail = $message->setTo($name);
    } else {
        $toEmail = $message->setTo([$address => $name]);
    }
    $numSent += $this->mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
  }

  if($bypassSpool) {
    $spool = $this->mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
  $transport = \Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $spool->flushQueue($transport);
}

}
```

So whenever the last parameter of that function was set to **true**, the emails got sent out immediately and weren't stored for spooling.

For my situation now, I'd like to have the same thing, but of course I'm calling the wrong **flushQueue** function because I'm probably not accessing the right spooler. Does anybody know how to access the spooler from that bundle?

The service class from that bundle:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rafael
 * Date: 02/05/2015
 * Time: 22:16
 */

namespace Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Spool;


use Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Entity\Email;
use Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Entity\EmailRepository;
use Swift_Mime_Message;
use Swift_Transport;

class DatabaseSpool extends \Swift_ConfigurableSpool {
    /**
     * @var EmailRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    private $parameters;

    public function __construct(EmailRepository $repository, $parameters)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }


    /**
     * Starts this Spool mechanism.
     */
    public function start()
    {
        // TODO: Implement start() method.
    }

    /**
     * Stops this Spool mechanism.
     */
    public function stop()
    {
        // TODO: Implement stop() method.
    }

    /**
     * Tests if this Spool mechanism has started.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isStarted()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Queues a message.
     *
     * @param Swift_Mime_Message $message The message to store
     *
     * @return bool    Whether the operation has succeeded
     */
    public function queueMessage(Swift_Mime_Message $message)
    {
        $email = new Email();
        $email->setFromEmail(implode('; ', array_keys($message->getFrom())) );

        if($message->getTo() !== null ){
            $email->setToEmail(implode('; ', array_keys($message->getTo())) );
        }
        if($message->getCc() !== null ){
            $email->setCcEmail(implode('; ', array_keys($message->getCc())) );
        }
        if($message->getBcc() !== null ){
            $email->setBccEmail(implode('; ', array_keys($message->getBcc())) );
        }
        if($message->getReplyTo() !== null ){
            $email->setReplyToEmail(implode('; ', array_keys($message->getReplyTo())) );
        }

        $email->setBody($message->getBody());
        $email->setSubject($message->getSubject());
        $email->setMessage($message);

        $this->repository->addEmail($email);
    }

    /**
     * Sends messages using the given transport instance.
     *
     * @param Swift_Transport $transport A transport instance
     * @param string[] $failedRecipients An array of failures by-reference
     *
     * @return int     The number of sent emails
     */
    public function flushQueue(Swift_Transport $transport, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        if (!$transport->isStarted())
        {
            $transport->start();
        }

        $count = 0;
        $emails = $this->repository->getEmailQueue($this->getMessageLimit());

        foreach($emails as $email){
            /*@var $message \Swift_Mime_Message */
            $message = $email->getMessage();
            try{
                $count_= $transport->send($message, $failedRecipients);
                if($count_ > 0){
                    $this->repository->markCompleteSending($email);
                    $count += $count_;
                }else{
                    throw new \Swift_SwiftException('The email was not sent.');
                }
            }catch(\Swift_SwiftException $ex){
                $this->repository->markFailedSending($email, $ex);
            }
        }

        return $count;
    }
}
```

and the services.yml file:

```
services:
repository.email:
    class: Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Entity\EmailRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager',getRepository]
    arguments: ['CitraxDatabaseSwiftMailerBundle:Email']
citrax.database.swift_mailer.spool:
    class: Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Spool\DatabaseSpool
    arguments: ['@repository.email', '%citrax_database_swift_mailer.params%']
swiftmailer.spool.db:
    alias: citrax.database.swift_mailer.spool
swiftmailer.mailer.default.spool.db:
    alias: citrax.database.swift_mailer.spool
```

Comment: flushQueue method will get accessible from citrax.database.swift_mailer.spool service.

Comment: hmm thanks! when I do this, my messages get failed.. any idea why that might be?
I have this:
        if($bypassSpool) {
          $spool = $this->container->get('citrax.database.swift_mailer.spool');
        $transport = \Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
          $spool->flushQueue($transport);
      }

but everytime I try it, the email get's into the database with status "Failed"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.